# Static image vs dynamic image resizing

Tags: php, image, performance

I'm developing a web-page with multiple holidays on it. All these holidays have their associated images but I'm considering using dynamic image resizing instead of developing a script to resize all images as static icons.

What are the performance implications associated with dynamic image resizing and is it that bad? i.e. https://placekitten.com/g/300/300

The reason for this is it will reduce storage requirements substantially but at the same time I don't want to sabotage the user's page-load experience.